# Likely Xrandr: How to create a single virtual monitor on linux so that APIs don't see the physical ones anymore? Not by xorg conf files

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr

I need to have a single virtual monitor on linux. External APIs or apps are not allowed to recognize that two or more physical monitors are attached. Think like Teamviewer not seeing multiple monitors but only one.

Background: We run a server based that plays  advertisements on displays. However, it can only adress max 2 physical monitors. As such, a solution we are trying to get is to get a large virtual monitor based upon multiple physical ones and then divide the contents among them as layouts.

What I have tried: Xorg.config files to begin with. But my issue was that either parts of it got overwritten by other stuff, or that some options or extensions/modules - like Xinerama - were not loaded or ignored, and spent like 2 weeks on this alone. I highly prefer to not fiddle with these xorg-config files again because I likely get into the issues again of it not loading properly

So I decided to focus on xrandr instead. I am not sure if I did get it successfully in-between. I basically run stuff like:

```
xrandr --fb 3840x1080
xrandr --setmonitor virt 3840/400x1080/300+0+0 HDMI-1,HDMI-2
xrandr --newmode "3840x1080_60.00"  346.00  3840 4088 4496 5152  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "3840x1080_60.00"
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 "3840x1080_60.00"
xrandr --size "3840x1080_60.00" --output HDMI-1
xrandr --size "3840x1080_60.00" --output HDMI-2
```

Any advice on the issue and how to solve it?

System: Ubuntu 20.04, modified
The host is a Gigabyte mini computer with one internal GPU.